# RFC 1867 file upload from perl

Tags: perl, upload, wav, multipart, rfc

I need do an RFC 1867 upload to a server of the raw data (without riff headers) of a wav file. I have written a perl script to do this. Looks like this:

```
my $wav = new Audio::Wav;
my $read = $wav->read($wavtoupload);
my $rawdata = $read->read_raw($read->length()); #raw data w/o riff

my $url = "http://thehost.com";
my $req = HTTP::Request->new();
$req = POST $url,
   Referer => 'hxxp://www.mydomain.com/some.php3', 
   Accept_Language => 'en-us',
   Content_Type => 'form-data',
   Accept_Encoding => 'wav',
   User_Agent => 'Mozilla/4.0',
   Host => 'www.mydomain.com',
   Connection => 'Keep-Alive',
   Content => [ $rawdata ];
print $req->as_string;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $resp = $ua->request($req);

if ($resp->is_success) {
   #...
}
```

According to http://search.cpan.org/~ether/HTTP-Message-6.11/lib/HTTP/Request/Common.pm:

> "The POST method also supports the *multipart/form-data* content used for Form-based File Upload as specified in RFC 1867. You trigger this content format by specifying a content type of 'form-data' as one of the request headers."

However, the server is receiving Content_Type = "form-data" is doesn't like it because it expects "multipart/form-data". Also the Content_Length is 0, and the body isn't being uploaded.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273071/how-does-rfc-2854-obsolete-rfc-1867 is worth reading

Comment: don't think that helps. we have no control over the server that wants the RFC 1867 upload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post the output of:

```
print $req->as_string;
```

One thing you are doing wrong is you are not assembling your data into key/value pairs, which is how all HTTP requests organize their data.

> Also the Content_Length is 0

That's because all the data is being used as the key part of a key/value pair, thus there is no value, and no value has a Content-Length of 0.

Nevertheless, the server should not be receiving the header:

```
Content_Type = "form-data"
```

For the raw request, I get:

```
POST http://thehost.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: wav
Accept-Language: en-us
Host: www.mydomain.com
Referer: hxxp://www.mydomain.com/some.php3
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0
Content-Length: 82
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=xYzZY

--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mydata"

hello world
--xYzZY--
```

As you can clearly see, the Content-Type header is `multipart/form-data`.  That's because:

> You trigger this content format by specifying a content type of
>   'form-data' as one of the request headers.

In other words, the perl module creates the header `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` in the actual request.

Here's the code I used:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use Data::Dumper;
use HTTP::Message;
use HTTP::Request::Common;

my $rawdata = "hello world";
my $url = "http://thehost.com";

my $requ = POST $url,
   Referer => 'hxxp://www.mydomain.com/some.php3', 
   Accept_Language => 'en-us',
   Content_Type => 'form-data',
   Accept_Encoding => 'wav',
   User_Agent => 'Mozilla/4.0',
   Host => 'www.mydomain.com',
   Connection => 'Keep-Alive',
   Content => [ mydata => $rawdata ];

say $requ->as_string;
```

The following shows the difference between specifying a key/value pair v. just specifying a value:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use Data::Dumper;
use HTTP::Message;
use HTTP::Request::Common;

my $rawdata = "hello world";
my $url = "http://thehost.com";

my $requ = POST $url,
   Referer => 'hxxp://www.mydomain.com/some.php3', 
   Accept_Language => 'en-us',
   Content_Type => 'form-data',
   Accept_Encoding => 'wav',
   User_Agent => 'Mozilla/4.0',
   Host => 'www.mydomain.com',
   Connection => 'Keep-Alive',
   Content => [ 
       mykey => 'myValue',
       $rawdata, 
   ];


say $requ->as_string;

--output:--
POST http://thehost.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: wav
Accept-Language: en-us
Host: www.mydomain.com
Referer: hxxp://www.mydomain.com/some.php3
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0
Content-Length: 142
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=xYzZY

--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mykey"  #<===HERE

myValue  #<======AND HERE
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="hello world"  #<===COMPARED TO

        #<======COMPARED TO
--xYzZY--
```

The bare value ends up being used as the key, and because there is no value the Content-Length ends up being 0.

According to the [docs](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/HTTP-Message-6.11/lib/HTTP/Request/Common.pm), here is how you should specify a file upload:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use Data::Dumper;
use HTTP::Message;
use HTTP::Request::Common;

my $rawdata = "hello world";
my $url = "http://thehost.com";

my $requ = POST $url,
   Referer => 'hxxp://www.mydomain.com/some.php3', 
   Accept_Language => 'en-us',
   Content_Type => 'form-data',
   Accept_Encoding => 'wav',
   User_Agent => 'Mozilla/4.0',
   Host => 'www.mydomain.com',
   Connection => 'Keep-Alive',
   Content => [ 
       mykey => 'myValue',         #some other key/value pair
       cool_sounds => [undef,      #file upload key/value pair
                       'myfile.wav', 
                       Content => $rawdata
                      ] 

   ];


say $requ->as_string;

--output:--
POST http://thehost.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: wav
Accept-Language: en-us
Host: www.mydomain.com
Referer: hxxp://www.mydomain.com/some.php3
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0
Content-Length: 176
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=xYzZY

--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mykey"

myValue
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cool_sounds"; filename="myfile.wav"

hello world
--xYzZY--
```

If you need to set the Content-Type for the file section, you can do it like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use Data::Dumper;
use HTTP::Message;
use HTTP::Request::Common;

my $rawdata = "hello world";
my $url = "http://thehost.com";

my $requ = POST $url,
   Referer => 'hxxp://www.mydomain.com/some.php3', 
   Accept_Language => 'en-us',
   Content_Type => 'form-data',
   Accept_Encoding => 'wav',
   User_Agent => 'Mozilla/4.0',
   Host => 'www.mydomain.com',
   Connection => 'Keep-Alive',
   Content => [ 
       mykey => 'myValue',         #some other key/value pair
       cool_sounds => [undef,      #file upload key/value pair
                       'myfile.wav', 
                       'Content-Type' => 'audio/x-wav', 
                       Content => $rawdata
                      ]  #=>If one of the values in the $form_ref is an array reference...

   ];


say $requ->as_string;

--output:--
OST http://thehost.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: wav
Accept-Language: en-us
Host: www.mydomain.com
Referer: hxxp://www.mydomain.com/some.php3
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0
Content-Length: 203
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=xYzZY

--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mykey"

myValue
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cool_sounds"; filename="myfile.wav"
Content-Type: audio/x-wav

hello world
--xYzZY--
```

And, if you need to set the Content-Disposition of the file section to something else:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use Data::Dumper;
use HTTP::Message;
use HTTP::Request::Common;

my $rawdata = "hello world";
my $url = "http://thehost.com";

my $requ = POST $url,
   Referer => 'hxxp://www.mydomain.com/some.php3', 
   Accept_Language => 'en-us',
   Content_Type => 'form-data',
   Accept_Encoding => 'wav',
   User_Agent => 'Mozilla/4.0',
   Host => 'www.mydomain.com',
   Connection => 'Keep-Alive',
   Content => [ 
       mykey => 'myValue',         #some other key/value pair
       cool_sounds => [undef,      #file upload key/value pair
                       'myfile.wav', 
                      'Content-Type' => 'audio/x-wav', 
                      'Content-Disposition' => 'file',
                       Content => $rawdata
                      ]

   ];


say $requ->as_string;

--output:--
POST http://thehost.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: wav
Accept-Language: en-us
Host: www.mydomain.com
Referer: hxxp://www.mydomain.com/some.php3
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0
Content-Length: 155
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=xYzZY

--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mykey"

myValue
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: file
Content-Type: audio/x-wav

hello world
--xYzZY--
```

Note that in this case there's no name attribute for the file section.

By the way, what made you think that not posting your `use statements` was helpful?  Don't do that.

Comment: "which is how all HTTP requests organize their data" — that isn't true, that's just how the two standard request encodings you can trigger from a standard HTML form organise their data.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. My issue was simply that the Content section wasn't in the right format.