# 2018 way of creating an upload file progress bar

Tags: django, nginx, file-upload

The research I've done sofar led me to techologies that seem out of date. I wonder if there is a right/common way to upload files and get progress info in 2018.

I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273071/how-does-rfc-2854-obsolete-rfc-1867) that RFC1867 is obsolete

I'm trying to setup NGINX Upload Progress Bar but it uses json**p** in its response and I've also [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about) that I should not use jsonp.

My stack is NGINX, Gunicorn, Ubuntu, Django 2.1, React

I'm trying to avoid jquery

I only need last version of Firefox and Chrome to be supported

Note : I'm only intersted in the client/server communication part, for UI I use react semantic ui progress

Comment: In 2018? I'd use the HTML5 file API. No need to make any changes in the backend because everything happens in the browser. You can find the relevant code in [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#Handling_the_upload_process_for_a_file).

Comment: you can take a look at https://github.com/ouhouhsami/django-progressbarupload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now use HTML5 file API Thanks to @xyres comment.